# Using an array of null instead of an optional

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I was wondering why an array of nulls of size 1 instead an optional:

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test-common/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataTestUtil.kt#L27

Original code:

```
    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    fun <T> getValue(liveData: LiveData<T>): T {
        val data = arrayOfNulls<Any>(1)
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        val observer = object : Observer<T> {
            override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
                data[0] = o
                latch.countDown()
                liveData.removeObserver(this)
            }
        }
        liveData.observeForever(observer)
        latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        return data[0] as T
    }
```

why not using:

```
 @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    fun <T> getValue(liveData: LiveData<T>): T {
        var data: T? = null
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        val observer = object : Observer<T> {
            override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
                data = o
                latch.countDown()
                liveData.removeObserver(this)
            }
        }
        liveData.observeForever(observer)
        latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        return data!!
    }
```

Is it better to use an array than an optional object there? why?
Or it's just the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the project [history](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/commit/724cc1bd6ed11171a0bbf4a3a29977fac053777e#diff-ea0e8cb45bc54def00e8b26cca43da46), the file used to be Java, but was translated directly into Kotlin - the original Java version is [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/b1a194c1ae267258cd002e2e1c102df7180be473/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test-common/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataTestUtil.java), and you can see they just converted it directly to Kotlin.

While the version you gave makes more sense in Kotlin, there is no such capability in Java, because local variables you use in an anonymous class or lambda have to be final. That is why a single element array is used instead. But if they had written it originally in Kotlin (or if they were to refactor it), they would almost certainly do it the way you did.